# Difference in behaviour of List<Object> vs Set<Object> in Apex

Tags: apex

I have read [this SO post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33069/why-is-my-setobject-reference-not-able-to-point-to-a-setsomespecificobject-c), but I am asking a slightly different question:

I would like to be able to write a method that can accept a `Set` with any parameterized type.

e.g. `myMethod(Set<Object> genericSet)`

If I were wanting to do the same thing with a `List`, then I could using `List<Object>` because the following is possible:

`List<Object> genericList = new List<String>();`

In other words `List<Object>` can act as an abstraction of `List<String>`.

However, I can't use `Set<Object>` as a method parameter and expect to be able to pass in `Set<String>` because the following throws a compilation error:

`Set<Object> genericSet = new Set<String>();`

I'm not sure why this is. Possibly something to do with the fact that different types have different `hashCode()` functions?

*Alternative*

As an alternative, I could just have my parameter be of type `Object`, which would allow me to pass in any type of `Set<?>`. However, the problem with this is that I need to check that the argument passed in is indeed a Set of some sort. Furthermore, if it is, then because generic sets aren't allowed, I would need to know the exact type so that I can cast it to the correct set type.

I can't use `myArg instanceof Set` because Set has to has some sort of parameterized type.

And because of the issue I outlined above, I can't use `myArg instanceof Set<Object>` because this will return false for everything except when the parameterized type really is `Object`.

Does anyone know how I might be able to get some sort of generic behaviour for Sets?

Comment: Reading your question and the one you cite, it seems to me that the cited question already answers yours, but there are a bunch of related Q&As such as [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155768/mapobject-listsobject-cannot-be-cast-to-mapstring-listaccount/155772#155772) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/apex-string-instanceof-object).

Comment: In two words: Type Erasure. In more than two words, [Is there a specific reason why we can't upcast sets?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145428/is-there-a-specific-reason-why-we-cant-upcast-sets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type system is oddly broken in a number of ways that they're also broken in Java, in addition to a [unique set of problems in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/106068/) that Phil W linked to.

However, if you're interested in a solution, you can indeed use sets and lists interchangeably through the use of Iterable. Unfortunately, it will require a cast every time you want to use it. Here's an Execute Anonymous script you can check out.

```
void printValues(Iterable<Object> v) {
    Object[] values = new Object[0];
    Iterator<Object> it = v.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        values.add(it.next());
    }
    System.debug(values);
}
Set<String> setOfString = new Set<String>{'hello','world'};
printValues((Iterable<Object>)setOfString);
List<String> listOfString = new List<String>{'hello','world'};
printValues((Iterable<Object>)listOfString);
```

Notice how we can extract values from a list or set of any time if we cast it to Iterable first. Unfortunately, we still can't get to a "concrete" type dynamically, but you can use this on a case-by-case basis to work within the limitations of Apex.

Comment: thanks very much for your comment. Although what I was trying to say and probably expressing badly is that I only wanted to use Sets. So I need to internally check that the Object passed into the method is a Set (of any type). I don't believe this is possible because you have to include the parameterised type, and Set<Object> only works when using instance of for Sets of Objects and not Sets for any other type.

Comment: @lemming You can't cast Sets between different types, unfortunately. That's just how they work. Iterable is your only real path forward.